# Find transformation to align two polygons at fixed points?

Tags: mathematics, textures, graphics, geometry, transformation

#### Problem

I have a source image (arbitrary width and height **c**) shown here as a rectangle `[X1,X2,X3,X4]`. It contains two points **C** and **D** (both known coordinates within the image - **X4** / top left).

[image: Source image]

Then I have a target image (might have different height **a** and width **b** than source image) that contains two points **A** and **B** (**|AB|** doesn't necessarily equal **|CD|**). There's also a source of projection **S**.

[image: Target image]

I need to somehow calculate coordinates of a transformed rectangle (polygon) such that:

1. Point **C** will always be mapped to **A** (therefore **A** will be equal to **C**) and **D** will be mapped to **B** (**B** = **D**)
2. Point **X3** of this newly calculated polygon will lie on a line between **S** and **A/C** (now identical)
3. Point **X4** will lie on a line from **S** to **B/D**.
4. Distance from parallel lines `[X1,X2]` and `[X3,X4]` will be still **c**. *(If it turns out that it's not always possible to construct such a polygon the condition 4. can be dropped, and `[X1,X2]` don't need to be parallel to `[X3,X4]` as well)*

*(see below)*

[image: Result image]

#### What I've tried

I thought I will solve it by:

1. shrinking width of source image by ratio of **|AB|** and **|CD|**
2. aligning **C** with **A** (move source image)
3. finding angle difference  between **AB** and **CD**
4. rotating source image by angle  (with center in **C/A**)
5. calculating **X3** and **X4**

But it doesn't work universally. Steps 1-4 work well, but then changing **X3** and **X4** moves **C** (resp. **D**) away from **A** (resp. **B**).

Comment: Can you give us some context of what's motivating these geometric transformations? It looks like we might be doing some kind of perspective matching/correction, but knowing the details could remove ambiguity or even open the door to known solutions for that particular application.

Comment: It's casting a shadow in a 2D isometric game. I have images (sprites) for 8 directions of "rotation". By itself they're used just plainly as a sprite, but then depending on light direction I determine the best direction of "shadow" I turn pixels to black and cast this shadow to a polygon created by "3D" cone from 3D light position. I know height (c) of the entity. It works well for entities having one ground point (like a person or a column). I'm trying to generalize algorithm for things with 2 or more points. I figured out I need to match nearest 2 ground points (imagine a bench for example).

Comment: So target image is sprite to be drawn and source image is a different rotation of this sprite (usually the same width and height, but not always) used as a shadow. Result is a polygon of - to be cast - shadow. It's not precise shadow of course, but it works reasonably well (at least for one point), but I tried drawing it (manually) and it looks OK for two points as well. Thus this question.

Comment: Can we make some assumptions about the setup of your shadow image - eg. that points C & D are at the same height, and equally spaced left & right from the center of the quad? (This would put the pre-image of S on the center line, at a fixed height below the bottom of the image). For full generality we might sometimes need to skew/shear the image - is that supported in your case?

Comment: For me the shadow is just quad so any transformation is possible skew/shear or any other. For me it is a free transform polygon basically. It doesn't even have to be transform per se (if the points are somehow magically calculated). 'c' and 'd' are just height (c = X2.y - X3.y) and width of source image as well as 'a' and 'b' are just height and width of target image. I marked them to denote that 'a' and 'c' can be different and 'b' and 'd' as well.

Comment: And about *points* C & D? Any standards about their positioning we might be able to assume?

Comment: C should be equal to A and D should be equal to B.

Comment: That's the mapping of *the images of* C & D. I'm asking about their positions in their original quad.

Comment: They can be placed anywhere in the image because they're taken from a set of 4 points that signify the ground polygon (used for collision detection). But I would say that mostly they're more in the bottom half (more near the ground), but not necessarily.